# How to use if statment inside div tags with streamlit (bootstrap card)

Tags: python, if-statement, streamlit, bootstrap-cards

How to use `if statement` inside **div** tags with **streamlit** ?
I am using **bootstrap card** with **streamlit** to display info from dataframe  .
What i need is to be able to display the content inside the **bootstrap card** when its not empty and hide the info when its empty .

code:

```
def card(ID,name,nickname,mother_name,bd):

    return f'''

    <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem;">

        <div class="card-body">

            <h5 class="card-title">ID: {ID}</h5>

            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Name: {name}</h6>

            <p class="card-text">Nickname: {nickname}</p>

            <p class="card-text">Date of Birth: {bd}</p>

            <p class="card-text">Mother Name: {mother_name}</p>

        </div>

    </div>

    '''
st.markdown("""

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

""",unsafe_allow_html=True)

df_result_search = pd.DataFrame()
with st.sidebar.form(key='search_form',clear_on_submit= False):
     regular_search_term=st.text_input("Enter Search Term")
     if st.form_submit_button("search"):
         df_result_search = df[df['name'].str.contains(regular_search_term)|df['nickname'].str.contains(regular_search_term)|df['mother_name'].str.contains(regular_search_term)]
                        
                            
 st.write("{} Records ".format(str(df_result_search.shape[0])))
 for index ,row in df_result_search.iterrows():
         st.markdown(card(
                            row[0],
                            row[1],
                            row[2],
                            row[3],
                            row[4],
    ),unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use style on display, if none we hide it. Results will be displayed for up to a max of 5 columns. Turn ON the wide mode if necessary.

#### Code

```
import math

import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd



data = {
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    'name': ['peter', 'john', 'james', 'james', 'james', 'james', 'james', 'james', 'james'],
    'nickname': ['pet', 'jon', None, 'james', 'jem', 'jack', 'jo', 'mes', 'ja'],
    'mother_name': ['maria', 'linda', 'ana', 'beth', 'vivian', 'rose', 'meg', 'sharon', 'neda'],
    'bd': ['2000-05-15', '2006-09-12', '2004-10-25', '1999-01-08', '2009-12-14', '2001-11-20', '1999-05-12', '2009-01-28', '2009-03-14']    
}

st.markdown("""
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
    integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
""",unsafe_allow_html=True)


def card(ID,name,nickname,mother_name,bd, v1, v2, v3, v4):
    return f'''
    <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">ID: {ID}</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="display: {v1};">Name: {name}</h6>
            <p class="card-text" style="display: {v2};">Nickname: {nickname}</p>
            <p class="card-text" style="display: {v3};">Date of Birth: {bd}</p>
            <p class="card-text" style="display: {v4};">Mother Name: {mother_name}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    '''

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
st.write(df)

df_result_search = pd.DataFrame()
with st.sidebar.form(key='search_form',clear_on_submit= False):
     regular_search_term=st.text_input("Enter Search Term")
     if st.form_submit_button("search"):
         df_result_search = df[df['name'].str.contains(regular_search_term) |
                               df['nickname'].str.contains(regular_search_term) |
                               df['mother_name'].str.contains(regular_search_term)]
                        

rec = df_result_search.shape[0]
st.write("{} Records ".format(str(rec)))

num_rows = max(1, math.ceil(rec/5))

# Save cards data temporarily.
dv = 'inherit'
cards = []
for index, row in df_result_search.iterrows():
    v1 = dv if row[1] is not None else 'none'
    v2 = dv if row[2] is not None else 'none'
    v3 = dv if row[3] is not None else 'none'
    v4 = dv if row[4] is not None else 'none'
    cards.append([row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], v1, v2, v3, v4])

# Show the card data.
if len(cards):
    for r in range(num_rows):
        num_cols = min(5, max(1, rec))
        c = st.columns(num_cols)
        for m in range(num_cols):
            if len(cards):
                mycard = cards.pop(0)
                c[m].markdown(card(*mycard), unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer 
But what i meant if the content inside the card like the **nickname**  is empty 
I will display the card without the **filed  nickname**

Comment: What if I will empty the nickname of peter, is that your data would look like? I can show that as well.

Comment: So based on your output let say the record number 3 
Has id = 3  name= james  (nickname = nan or null ) db = 2004-10-25
The output card will include all fields without the nickname  so it display 
Id | name | bd 

And one more question what if i want to divide the cards on many columns  
Let say 3 columns  so if returned result includes 3 records it will display each card on columns beside each other horizontally.
Thanks you.

Comment: I will update the answer later.

Comment: The last update for the answer is still not getting me the correct answer  beacuse it still display  the word  **nickname** where as what i want to display  is just 
Id =1
Name = peter
Mother_name=maria
Bd= 2000-05-15

Comment: Answer updated, nickname is not shown.

Comment: Added code to show cards horizontally

Comment: i tried your answer but when i have more records it crash and display the below error :

`IndexError: list index out of range
Traceback:

File "f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 443, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "F:\AIenv\streamlit\TEC_APPS\fit_in_out_leb.py", line 1520, in <module>
    main()
File "F:\AIenv\streamlit\TEC_APPS\fit_in_out_leb.py", line 590, in main
    with c[cnt]:`

Comment: What is your maximum records?

Comment: sometimes i would have 50 records but what i want is to be able to display these records on 3 or 4 or 5 columns

Comment: Try to solve your issue with displaying up to a max of 5 columns. If you cannot solve it in one or two days comeback and we will solve it.

Comment: for sure while i am asking you i am trying to solve it thank you for your help

Comment: Answer updated, it can now arrange cards up to a max of 5 columns if there are more they will be put in the next row.